# Convert formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Please help me to adopt below formulas to vba format:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(64),A2)+1,LEN(A2))
```

and

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,MTLS!B:B,0))=TRUE,"MTLS","NOT MTLS")
```

My approach is working only to first formula:

```
With WS1.Range("AP2:AP" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=MID(T2,FIND(CHAR(64),T2)+1,LEN(T2))"
        End With
```

Second one gives an "Syntax error".

```
            With WS1.Range("AP2:AP" & LastRow)
               .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,MTLS!B:B,0))=TRUE,"MTLS","NOT MTLS")"
                  End With
```

Comment: Quotes in the the string need to be doubled: `"MTLS"` should be `""MTLS""` and so on.

Comment: you also do not need the `=TRUE` part.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VBEditor, show Immediate window (Ctrl+G if you haven't it visible already). Select cell with formula in the spreadsheet. Type in the Immediate:

```
?Selection.formula
```

and you get it. If you want to use it in the code, you need to double "s. Or you may type in immediate:

```
?Replace(cl.Formula, """", """""")
```

You will get formula with doubled quotation marks.